# Изменил Path на Windows 10 и теперь Stable Deffusion не запускается

Tags: анимация, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, поиск-пути, файловые-пути

Я изменил Path для Windows 10 и теперь не работает Stable Deffusion. Опишу проблему точнее: Для работы TemporalKit для анимации, согласно этому сайту: "https://github.com/CiaraStrawberry/TemporalKit" мне нужно было установить ffmpeg через командную строку, однако он почему-то не устанавливался и выдавал - "Ошибка установки ffmpeg" [image: пробы запуска и установки ffmpeg](1 и 2 скрин) [image: попытки прописывания пути к ffmpeg по пути setx /M path "%path%;C:\ваш\путь без изменения PATH], тогда я решил посетить этот сайт; "https://blog.pruffme.com/instrukciya-po-ustanovke-i-rabote-s-programmoj-ffmpeg-na-windows/" и поменять PATH чтобы всё-таки установить  ffmpeg  - как итог у меня и правда всё заработало [image: Код запуска ffmpeg для командной строки](скрин 3), но после перезагрузки командной строки, чтобы все изменения применились - у меня перестал работать Stable Deffusion и стал выдавать такую ошибку [image: Сама ошибка SD] и подводку к ошибке в красном квадрате в командной строке [image: Описание ошибки в SD] и [image: Описание ошибки в SD] (скрин 4-6). Чтобы решить эту проблему самостоятельно я уже и удалил Path который до этого записал в системную переменную и восстановил систему от 05.07.2023года (я вчера химичил, поэтому 05 должно было сработать) и попытался восстановить(добавить) старые переменные PATH, согласно инструкции с этого сайта - https://winreviewer.com/kak-vosstanovit-peremennuyu-path-posle-udaleniya/ Итог: ничего не поменялось(, ничего не работает. Помоги пожалуйста

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)